# When is a measure a product measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A_1})$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$ be two measurable spaces and lets consider the measure space $(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_1\times \mathcal{A}_2, \mu_p)$.

Under which conditions is it possible to factorize $\mu_p$ meaning that we have $\mu_p=\mu_1\times\mu_2$ where $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are measure on the spaces mentioned.

For example, I know that if $\Omega_1=\mathbb{R}^n,\Omega_2=\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathcal{A}_1=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n), \mathcal{A}_2=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ we can write the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure as the product on the individual spaces, which is $\lambda^{m+n}=\lambda^n\cdot\lambda^m$

I also know that it is not always possible if we pick the measurable spaces arbitrarily.

So is it always possible if we have something like $\Omega_1=X^n, \Omega_2=X^m$ and create some $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ *in the same way*, e.g. the Borel algebra?

What in general do I have to assume for this to work?

Comment: First of all, can we clear up some terminology?  Usually "measurable space" means a set equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra (but without specifying any particular measure on that $\sigma$-algebra), and "measure space" is a set equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra and a measure.

Comment: And I'm not really sure what you're asking in this question.  No matter what measurable spaces $(\Omega_i, \mathcal{A}_i)$ you consider, unless they are something really trivial, the product $(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_1\times \mathcal{A}_2)$ will always admit some measures which are product measures and some measures which are not.

Comment: Are you asking: what are some other conditions on the *measure* $\mu_p$ itself, that are equivalent to it being a product measure?  One condition is to consider the [disintegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem) of $\mu_p$ with respect to one of its marginals; it is a product measure iff its disintegration is constant.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, this is exactly what I am asking. Thanks for the interesting theorem! You say that there are almost always measures which are product measures and which are not. But then how do you choose the space you want to work when, for example, integrating. Consider a family of topological spaces $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and its topological product $X$. If $\mathcal{B}(X)\ne \bigotimes _{i\in I}\mathcal {B}(X_{i})$ then which one of the two should be used for the Lebesgue integral? I cannot apply something like Fubini anymore if they are not equal anymore, right?

Comment: Well, product measure is by definition a measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra, and Fubini's theorem is a theorem about product measure.  So if you want to work with a different $\sigma$-algebra on the product space, then by definition you are not dealing with product measure.  But this is one reason to work with Polish spaces and countable products, for in that case the product $\sigma$-algebra coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topological product.

Comment: Just to be sure, by product $\sigma$-algebra you mean the generated $\sigma$-algebra of the cartesian product of the $\sigma$-algebras, correct? Could you shortly elaborate on what you mean by "the product $\sigma$-algebra coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topological product"?

Comment: Yes, in other words, the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_1 \times \mathcal{A}_2$ is the one generated by all sets of the form $A_1 \times A_2$ where $A_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$.  Now let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ be topological spaces and $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_i)$ be their Borel $\sigma$-algebras.  Then one possible $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_1) \times \mathcal{B}(\Omega_2)$ as described above. [...]

Comment: Also, we may equip $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ with the product topology, and let $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by that topology.  Since open sets are Borel and products of open sets are open in the product topology, we always have $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_1) \times \mathcal{B}(\Omega_2) \subset \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.  We do not always have $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_1) \times \mathcal{B}(\Omega_2) = \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, but it does hold, for instance, when $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are Polish spaces, and in this case it also carries over to countable products.